# How to re.search html source with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, json

I bust my head but can not sort this out.

numbers, names are fictional. but the idea is like this

I read a link like 'https://graph.facebook.com/123'

this results to source code:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "first_name": "John",
   "last_name": "Doe",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/people/John-Doe/123",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

i want to extract all the information of id, name ,etc.

I try this but it fails

```
    link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/123'
    result = browser.open(link)
    text = result.read()
    result.close()
    id = re.search('"id": "(.*?)",', cont)
```

regex '"id": "(.*?)",' seems to be correct, but nothind is returned.. Why???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems JSON, you don't want to use regex to parse that.

```
link = 'https://graph.facebook.com/123'
result = browser.open(link)
data = json.load(result)
print data['id']
```

Comment: @user492741, you should click on the checkmark to the side of the answer then to accept it.